# Java Classes in different folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a large project and there are a large number of java and xml files in it.

I wanted to categories them. As far as I have understood I cant categories XML files in folders but I can categories the Java classes.

SO I made another Package in the SRC folder and put few java files in it. Its interacting with other java classes from other folder correctly but it is able able to refer to the layouts in setContentView(R.Layout.XX) its not getting any value from the layouts folder.

I am just in the learning phase, if you think this question is inappropriate then I am sorry but please dont give negative ratings.

Edit:

```
package testyourskills;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class TYSMain extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_content);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




}
```

If I transfer this class file back to the default package instead of the new package in the same SRC folder then its detecting all the XML files in the layout folder.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code from your problem activity?

Comment: Post the java code of a file you are referring to and the related xml that is giving you trouble

Comment: I have added the java code...and let it be any XML but its not showing any XML from the layout folder...

Comment: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an import android.R statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. Delete that import.

Comment: You should indeed remove Android.R import and perhaps import the .R file from the parent package (where your R file is generated)

Comment: Ohhh yeah how can forget that, silly me :(
But not its giving me error for R. Particularly for that folder only.
Already done project clean and all, its not generating R for that particular package...